# WDS Service cannot start

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-services, wds

I got WDS running on a Windows Server 2012 and for a moment i couldnt deploy image from the server to my new windows client. 
I tried restarting the Windows Deployments Service Server but the service wont start again.
It prompt that the path isnt right. Path - "C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k WDSServer".
svchost is listed in the mentioned path as suppose.

Any support here please.

Comment: Might this be a better fit for the Server Fault community?

Comment: You need to post the exact error message. Also, check server logs for errors from WDS or Service Manager that might give more clues as to why the service failed to start. WDS may have its own log.